# Drop columns from pandas dataframe, regardless of whether ALL column names are present

Tags: python, filter, pandas, dataframe

I would like to use `df.drop(drop_list, axis=1)` to remove a number of columns from my data frame, however if an entry from `drop_list` is not present in `df.columns.tolist()`, the command fails, how can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.drop(set(drop_list) & set(df.columns), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
df.drop(set.intersection(set(drop_list), df.columns.tolist()), axis=1)
```

(Edited following EdChum's comment)

Comment: you would need to cast the `drop_list` to a set otherwise you get a `TypeError: descriptor 'intersection' requires a 'set' object but received a 'list'` error. So `df.drop(set.intersection(set(drop_list), df.columns.tolist()), axis=1)` would work